# When I use Intellij IDEA to develope java program, there is always a debug configuration window. Then I can't even coding

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Here is an image of my problem.
[image]

How can I solve the problem?

This is really annoying.

Comment: Is the F9 key stuck on your keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new configuration and then IntelliJ IDEA will remember that.

[image: Config screen]

and then click on cross ([image: CROSS])

From that moment, IDE would NOT ask you to make this config again (if you don't want you to).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the problem is that I construct the project under directory of OneDrive, then this issue appears.